# Object directing to a property when accessed as an iterable

Tags: python, class, iteration

I'm trying to figure out if there's an elegant and concise way to have a class accessing one of its own properties when "used" as a dictionary, basically redirecting all the methods that'd be implemented in an ordered dictionary to one of its properties.

Currently I'm inheriting from IterableUserDict and explicitly setting its data to another property, and it seems to be working, but I know that UserDict is considered sort of old, and I'm concerned I might be overlooking something.

What I have:

```
class ConnectionInterface(IterableUserDict):
    def __init__(self, hostObject):
        self._hostObject= hostObject

        self.ports= odict.OrderedDict()
        self.inputPorts= odict.OrderedDict()
        self.outputPorts= odict.OrderedDict()

        self.data= self.ports
```

This way I expect the object to behave and respond (and be used) the way I mean it to, except I want to get a freebie ordered dictionary behaviour on its property "ports" when it's iterated, items are gotten by key, something is looked up ala if this in myObject, and so on.

Any advice welcome, the above seems to be working fine, but I have an odd itch that I might be missing something.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end inheriting IterableUserDict and setting self.data explicitly worked out to what I needed and hasn't had any unforeseen consequences or added dodgyness when serialising and deserialising.

Sticking to my original solution I guess and can recommend it if anybody needs a simple and full fledged dict like behaviour on a selected subset of data in their own objects.

It's fairly simple and doesn't have particularly strict scalability or complexity requirements stressing it though.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can do this. The primary thing with dictionaries is the getattr and setattr methods, so you can implement the magic methods `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` something like this:

```
def __getattr__(self, key):
    return self.ports[key]

def __setattr__(self, key, value):
    self.ports[key] = value
```

If you want implementation for .keys() and .values() and stuff, just write them in this style:

```
def keys(self):
    return self.ports.keys()
```

Comment: In my specific case there's a slew of convenient methods in dictionaries beside just getting and setting attributes that fit a class attribute well, but wouldn't fit the whole class, that I'd like.

Between set, get, by key, by value, sorting popping etc. all things that apply to that attribute, but would amount to too much boilerplate to implement piecemeal.

I am wary of unforeseen consequences though, such as maybe compromising copies, serialisation etc. that might yield just the attribute instead of correctly spanning the whole object, but testing all potential uses would take me too long.